# Why the code is executing again even after the if condition returning false value?

Tags: php, function, if-statement, recursion

Consider below code :

```
<?php
  function test() {
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count."<br>";
    if($count < 2) {
      test();
      echo "In last line...".$count."<br>";
    }
    $count--;
    echo "Count Value : ".$count."<br>";
  }
  test();
?>
```

Output is as below :

```
1
2
Count Value : 1
In last line...1
Count Value : 0
```

I'm confused about the following part from the above output which is outlined with red colored border.

[image: following part from the above output]

I want to know after if returning false on becoming `$count = 2` the immediately following code line  `echo "Count Value : ".$count."<br>";` gets executed. Then, it is expected to stop the flow as it's the last statement.

1. Why the program flow is not stopping after printing the line Count
   Value : 1?
2. Then how the last two lines from the output are generating?
3. Who is calling the `test()` function again?
4. How does the static variable getting reset to 0 again and printing the last two lines of the output?
5. Does in recursion the remaining code after the function call gets executed as many times as the recursive function got called upon failure of the test condition?

Comment: Do you know what a static variable is? It keeps the value when function is entered, again. In this case it is 0 at first call, then you increment it. Checking for $count < 2 calls itself and increases, again. So now it is 2.

Comment: The first time, $count < 2, so it executes the second test() which is in the if statement. In the second one, $count = 2, so it doesn't execute a third test. When the second is over, it continues the first where it "stopped".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the execution...

```
1.first time calling test()
  -> initialized  static $count = 0;
  -> $count++//$count = 1
  -> echo $count."<br>";// output 1
  -> if($count < 2) { // here $count is 1 condition passed 

2.calling from if statement test()
  -> static $count = 0; // as it is static variable will not lose its value when the function exits and will still hold that value should the function be called again // so here $count is 1
  -> $count++ //$count = 2
   -> echo $count."<br>";// output 2
  ->if($count < 2) { // here $count is 2 condition failed 
  -> $count--;$count is 1 
  -> output Count Value : 1
  -> calling from if statement test() is completed.
  -> prints next statement "In last line...".$count."<br>";//In last line...1 //value from first time calling test() // output In last line...1
  -> $count--;$count is 0
  -> Count Value : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function test() 
{
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count."<br>";//first output is 1
    if($count < 2) //first time condition true(i.e 1<2) and second time it is false
   {
      test();
/* here you again calling same function then $count will became 2 and you did not return anything here so next code will get executed after complete of 2nd time function. if you set **return false** here then your marked output does not execute*/
  echo "In last line...".$count."<br>";//Here $count will be 1 because its continuing first statement
    }
    $count--;//first time $count is 2 here but you are decremented here so 1
             // second time $count is 1 because continuing first statement and again its decremented so value will became 0.
    echo "Count Value : ".$count."<br>";// first output is 1//second output is 0
}
test();
?>
```

Comment: if you set return true/false in if condition then remain code won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

One by one answers.

1.Why the program flow is not stopping after printing the line Count Value : 1?

=> Because printing the line Count Value : 1 is done on the 2nd call of the function test().

2.Then how the last two lines from the output are generating?

=> After finishing the 2nd call, it still needs to complete it's first call which start again at

```
    echo "In last line...".$count."<br>";
```

3.Who is calling the test() function again?

=> 2nd line of below code snippet  is calling function again.

```
    if($count < 2) {
      test();
      echo "In last line...".$count."<br>";
    }
```

3.How does the static variable getting reset to 0 again and printing the last two lines of the output?

=> static variable does not get reset, static will only initialize the variable once, and once initiated it wont bother with the value.

4.Does in recursion the remaining code after the function call gets executed as many times as the recursive function got called upon failure of the test condition?

=> Yes